# Div Grows in Height on font-size: 0px in nested link

Tags: html, css

I have the following code. It's a simplified code of a responsive design: In a certain screen size I want to show only the icon (blue - via `::before`) but not the text.

When I try to hide the mail address via `font-size: 0` (there will be an icon in the ::before) - the header grows in height.

Sure I could use `max-height` - but is there a cleaner solution?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xs2wre4r/

```
<div class="header"> 

<span class="store-contact-email">
  <a href="mailto:info@example.com">info@example.com</a>
</span>
</div>


<div class="header">

<span class="store-contact-email">
  <a class="hide" href="mailto:info@example.com">info@example.com</a>
</span>
</div>
```

Left .header frame is computed = 25px
  Right .header frame is computed =  30px

```
  .header {
    float: left;
  }
  .header .store-contact-email a:before {
      line-height: 18px;
      vertical-align: -36%;
      padding-right: 5px;
      background-color: blue;
      width: 30px;
      display: inline-block;
  }
  .header .store-contact-email a:before {
      content: "x";
  }

  .store-contact-email {
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
  .store-contact-email a  {
    font-size: 18px;
  }


  .store-contact-email a.hide  {
    font-size: 0px;
  }
```

Comment: _“When I try to hide the mail address via font-size: 0”_ – there’s better ways to hide element content … f.e. the text-indent method.

Comment: Doesn't work `.store-contact-email a.hide  {
  text-indent: -9999px;
}` -> no effect. If i use display: inline-block, also the blue area (the icon) removes

Comment: `font-size:0` is not always a good idea, because some browsers will use the minimum font size from the user preferences instead.

Comment: why you use font-size to hide, you can use display:none

Comment: @manu: I want to show the ::before (icon), but not the text

Comment: Please comment if you down vote....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the font sizes of the `::before` blocks.
Since the second one has a font size of 0 and a line height of 18, it will be vertically positioned around the baseline, with 9px above and 9px below. The first one (with the normal font size) will be positioned normally (depending on the exact font), with, say, 14px above and 4px below.

(You also have `vertical-align` on the `::before`, but that doesn't change the situation; it moves both `::before` blocks 6.48 pixels down.)

So since the second one is located 5px lower than the first one, the bottom of the bounding box will be pushed down by 5px.

To illustrate,

```css
span {
  font-size: 18px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 0, .4);
}
span::before {
  line-height: 18px;
  vertical-align: -36%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background: rgba(0, 255, 255, .4);
  width: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "x";
}
span.hide {
  font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<span>visible</span>
<span class="hide">invisible</span>
```

Solution: don't use the font-size:0 trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `font-size` of `::before`, as it's inheriting parent `font-size`.

```
.header .store-contact-email a:before {
    content: "x";
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

Or you can use `display` or `visibility`, just avoid `:before` to inherit that property.

Answer (score 1):

wrap the text with span and hide the span

```
    <div class="header">

  <span class="store-contact-email">
    <a class="hide" href="mailto:info@example.com"><span>info@example.com</span></a>
  </span>
</div>

.store-contact-email a.hide span  {
  display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Better to:-

(1) nest the text `info@example.com` inside another `span`, which will `display:none` under a breakpoint; or

(2) put the icon on `.store-contact-email:before` instead of `.store-contact-email a:before`.

---

The reason is that browsers often enforce a minimum font size for accessibility purposes.